# IIS Express will not start when running copy of project on different computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have created a brand new ASP.NET MVC 5 project in VS2015 Enterprise (update 3). It runs as expected on that machine. However, when I copy/paste the whole project to a different machine running VS2015 community edition (update 3), the site fails to load and I get the error message:

> The program '[1648] iisexpress.exe has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Here's the kicker - Creating a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project in VS community edition and copy/pasting and running it in VS2015 enterprise in the same way, however, works normally without any configuration changes. I have recreated the files in the users\documents\IISExpress folder as pointed out by other SO questions, tried changing ports, but to no avail.

EDIT: IIS immediately fails on launching, by the way. It sounds like a config issue, but I'm not sure what to check in this case.

Comment: Have you copied the hidden .vs folder?

Comment: Yes, that file was copied. Still no dice.

Comment: unless the file path remains the same, you should manually edit the applicationHost.config file in it.

Comment: I've deleted and allowed VS to recreate the file on build. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, what i did is just close all the visual studio instances and in your project folder clear the .vs file(mostly it's Hidden). after that open your project.